# Transaction uses one table multiple times with different locks

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, locking

Let’s consider the transaction:

```
Begin transaction
1 select from table(xlock)
2 insert into table
3 select from table
Rollbac
```

The question is: will transaction hold the xlock till transaction ends or it will be only for 1 and 2?

Comment: Why don't you conduct a simple test and discover for yourself what it does? You will learn more with that approach. Better question if why you think you need to outsmart the database engine and its locking logic. Do you need to do this at all? If you must, then at least use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: Do you know how to see how the locks are changing during the execution? The is a view that shows all active locks in the current moment but not historical ?